# VSTO Word activate ribbon tab

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ribbon

I have the following ribbon.xml in my word vsto add-in:

```
<tab id="TabLetters" getVisible="IsLettersTabVisible" label="Letters">
 <group id="LettersGroup" label="Letters">
  <toggleButton id="NewWithTemplate"
              label="New using template Controls"
              size="large"
              imageMso="FileNew"
              onAction="NewTemplated" />
  </toggleButton>
 </group>
</tab>
```

And the following code behind the click event:

```
public void NewTemplated(Office.IRibbonControl control, bool value)
{
  CloseDocument();

  var doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Add(Template: @"LETTER_V2.dotx", Visible: true);
  doc.Activate();

  _ribbon.ActivateTab("TabLetters");
}
```

I would have expected this to result in a new window with my ribbon tab opened, however it just remains the HOME tab that is visible/current.  How do I make it happen that my tab is the one that is visible?

Comment: Is this the exact contents of the `ribbon.xml`-file or just an example? If it is your file it is not valid XML, since the `toggleButton` tag is closed twice; first by `/>` and then by `</toggleButton>`.

Comment: I just made it a little bit smaller to display here.  My xml is valid!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two ways you can use to set the active tab:

`TabLetters.RibbonUI.ActivateTab("TabLetters");` or

```
Globals.Ribbons.CustomRibbon.Tabs[Your tab id].RibbonUI.ActivateTab("TabLetters");
```

Answer (score 3):

I found solution for excel 2007.

code :

```
int appVersion = Convert.ToInt32(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Version.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
if (appVersion >= 14 )            
{
    ThisRibbonCollection ribb = Globals.Ribbons;
    ribb.[Your Ribbon].ApplicationGroup.RibbonUI.ActivateTab("tab");                
}
else if(appVersion == 12)  // Specific to Office 2007 only.
{
                SendKeys.Send("%TAB%"); // use sendwait if you running it in thread.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2013, here's the code I needed to use:

```
try
{
    //  Attempt to set the my VSTO ribbon bar as the active ribbon.
    string controlID = Globals.Ribbons.GetRibbon<MikesRibbon>().MikesTab.ControlId.ToString();
    this.RibbonUI.ActivateTab(controlID);
}
catch
{
}
```

The bit I stumbled on was how to get the ControlID to pass to the `ActivateTab` function.

You need to open your `MikesRibbon.cs` file (or equivalent !) in VS2013.  It'll show how your Ribbon will look, with a gray `FILE` tab next to your Ribbon's tab name.

In this Designer screen, click on your ribbon's tab (i.e. the tab to the right of `FILE`), and your Properties window *will* now show a `ControlID` value now, which you can set to a value of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Just for all of you that have to support Office 2007 also (like me). Here's an (**ugly**, but working) solution for Office 2007:

1. Open the office application
2. Press ALT and then see the keyboard shortcut for your custom ribbon tab
3. In your code you can now send this keys via the *SendKeys.SendWait* function

Hope it helps someone. Regards, Jörg

---

Code:

```
    public void FocusMyCustomRibbonTab()
    {
        if (IsExcel2007())
        {
            Globals.Ribbons.GetRibbon<MyRibbon>().tabMyRibbonTab.KeyTip = "GGG";

            //Excel 2007: Must send "ALT" key combination to activate tab, here "GGG"
            SendKeys.Send("%");                       
            SendKeys.Send("{G}");                     
            SendKeys.Send("{G}");                     
            SendKeys.Send("{G}");                     
            SendKeys.Send("%");                       
        }
        else
        {
            //Excel 2010 or higher: Build in way to activate tab
            if (this.ribbon.RibbonUI != null)
            {
                this.ribbon.RibbonUI.ActivateTab("MY_RIBBON_TAB_NAME");
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool IsExcel2007()
    {
        return (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Version.StartsWith("12"));
    }
```

Comment: I've changed the sent keytip into "GGG" to avoid possible keytip-conflicts with other Add-Ins. Background: The keytip used before was "Y2". But if you have for example "Adobe PDFMaker COM Addin" installed, then this keytip is already used....

Comment: With Excel 2013, using ActivationTab() with either the name or Tag of my VSTO ribbon causes a "Value does not fall within the expected range." exception.  Dumb question: in VS2013, where do I find the "Tab Name" ?   I can open my Ribbon.cs file in designer, and see Tag and (Name) in Properties... but no IDs....

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2016 use RibbonUI.ActivateTabMso(controlID) to activate general Word Ribbon Tabs.

Additionally you can get the right reference to the Ribbon by adding in your AddIn:

```
static internal Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.OfficeRibbon rUI = null;


private void WorkBenchRibbon_Load(object sender, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        rUI = ((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.OfficeRibbon)sender).Ribbon;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you came here looking for a solution because you have tried any of the above things from within a Application.DocumentOpen event handler or some similar event but keep getting an error, you may be running into this roadblock.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/baa9a81d-aad3-4af5-9d0a-f945c26ffa18/activiating-a-ribbon-tab-for-vsto-for-a-workbook-solutions-when-a-workbook-is-loaded-net-4?forum=vsto

The short and not-so-sweet answer is that you cannot activate the tab until...later...by using a Timer and respond to the elapsed event.  Just hoping to save some folks time.