# How can I determine if my VSTO ribbon is active in Word

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-addins, word-addins, ribbonx

I have a VSTO project that creates a ribbon tab in Word.

In [this Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627553/vsto-word-activate-ribbon-tab) I can see how to force my ribbon tab to be activated.

No where can I find how to perform sort-of the reverse - i.e. I want to know whether my ribbon tab is active or not.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?  How to determine whether the ribbon tab that I can activate is still active at any other stage of the user interaction with Word?

Comment: Use events. Ribbon: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon and RibbonTab: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbontab

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that using the Outlook Object Model. As a possible workaround you can use the [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility).

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) doesn't provide anything for that. But you can use the `GetVisibleMso` method of the `CommandBars` class for checking whether a built-in controls is visible or not. You just need to pass the idMso value of the control to the method, see [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798). But the best way to get the job done is to use callbacks in your custom UI markup. For example, the `getVisible` callback is invoked when controls are going to be shown on the ribbon (your tab is active). Thus, you will always know your tab is visible.